# openjdk-8 is not installed correctly

Tags: java, openjdk

I accidently installed `openjdk-9-jre-headless` when I actually wanted `openjdk-8-jre-headless` using

```
sudo apt install openjdk-9-jre-headless
```

When I realized it I did

```
sudo apt remove --purge openjdk-9-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Now I have a strange situation here:

```
~$ java --version

The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

But:

```
~$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-8-jre-headless is already the newest version (8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**What do I have to do here?**

---

EDIT:

I already tried

```
~$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless --reinstall

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/27.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 160472 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3) over (8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
Setting up openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out:

```
sudo apt remove --purge openjdk-8-jre-headless
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install --reinstall openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Now I get as expected

```
~$  java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP solved it by removing java8 first then reinstall it. However, it does not always doable, if you have java dependencies already, for instance, a running apache server, or some other things require java runtime. In this case, first remove java9, then do the following by directly running `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" 1
```

modify the path to java8 if necessary.